# How to do JSON-RPC calls from Swift over a Unix Domain Socket

Tags: swift, macos, json-rpc

I have a JSON-rpc server which is running over a unix domain socket. The stack would be UDS->HTTP->JSON-RPC.

How do i write a client in Swift for this? With a quick google search i wasn't able to find any libraries that does this.
In Python i'd be able to connect to the socket using the https://github.com/msabramo/requests-unixsocket library. Then use a JSON-RPC library that will work with that connection.

The golang server code is very minimal:

```
func RunDaemon() {
        r := mux.NewRouter()
        // Create the server and register the service
        s := rpc.NewServer()
        s.RegisterCodec(json.NewCodec(), "application/json")
        s.RegisterService(new(Daemon), "")

        r.Handle("/rpc", s)
        err := os.RemoveAll("/tmp/daemon.sock")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Failed to remove old socket")
        }
        lnr, err := net.Listen("unix", "/tmp/daemon.sock")
        if err != nil {
                logging.Error("Failed to create socket")
        }
        http.Serve(lnr, r)
}
```

Comment: ? 

if http request -> UDS, try `httputil.DumpRequest` to string then send.
if UDS -> http request, packet content, send by post or other method.

Comment: I want to do this from Swift, not from Python. I guess httputil.DumRequest is only available in python?

Comment: httputil.DumpRequest  for golang